# Need help calculating population total and average using a bash awk script

Tags: shell-script, awk

Need someone to help calculate the total population for each region and print the regions name, population, and average population.

States.txt (file):

```
State           Population   SqMi      Region 
------------------------------------------
California           39.37   163.7       West
Texas                29.36   268.6      South
Florida              21.73    65.7      South
New_York             19.33    54.7  NorthEast
Pennsylvania         12.78    46.1  NorthEast
Illinois             12.59    57.9    Midwest
Ohio                 11.69    44.8    Midwest
Georgia              10.71    59.4      South
North_Carolina       10.60    53.8      South
Michigan             9.97    96.7    Midwest
```

**Output should look like""

```
Region Total Average
---------------------------
South 72.40 18.10
Midwest 34.25 11.42
NorthEast 32.11 16.05
West 39.37 39.37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  FNR>2{ total[$4]+=$2; count[$4]+=1 }
  END{
    print "Region Total Average"
    print "---------------------------"
    for (i in total){ printf "%s %.2f %.2f" ORS, i, total[i], total[i]/count[i] }
  }
' States.txt
```